# Python Selenium one element with different xpath using Try-Loop

Tags: python, selenium

there are some elements with different xpath like 'code' in the website:

```
.td[1]/div[4]/div
.td[1]/div[3]/div
null
```

if the xpath = .td[1]/div[4]/div, then there should be another ISIN code in .td[1]/div[3]/div
I want to access them all with:

```
driver.get('https://www.chinabondconnect.com/en/Primary/Primary-Information/Onshore.html')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Others').click()

try: 
    codes=[code.get_attribute('textContent') for code in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tb7']//tr[starts-with(@class,'tb2tr pg')]//td[1]/div[4]/div")]
    ISINs=[ISIN.get_attribute('textContent') for ISIN in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tb7']//tr[starts-with(@class,'tb2tr pg')]//td[1]/div[3]/div")]
except:
    try:
      codes=[code.get_attribute('textContent') for code in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tb7']//tr[starts-with(@class,'tb2tr pg')]//td[1]/div[3]/div")]                 
    except:
      codes = 'null'
#dateframe=...
```

But it will not return all issuers in the website, only just few ones, not sure why this happened, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: there are only 12 isin and 53 code, what did you expect?

Comment: Hi, but I expect the no value ones could return 'null' in dataframe, but it just eliminant the ones do not have code

Comment: so you want the isin and code length equal? use normal loop.

Comment: Did you want all 200 or so rows of it.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Hello, yes, I'd like to get all recorded issuers' codes/ISIN info (if does not have, just return 'null' or blank into the csv dataframe) also for matrurity the xpath is different ```("//table[@id='tb7']//tr[starts-with(@class,'tb2tr pg')]//td[3]/div[3]/span[2]")```or ```div[5]```, not sure how to deal with that situation..

Comment: Can you produce an example list for both.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have something like this. Which inserts null for no child elements of that td.

```
driver.get('https://www.chinabondconnect.com/en/Primary/Primary-Information/Onshore.html')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Others').click()
codes=[]
ISINs=[]
rows=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tb7']//tr[starts-with(@class,'tb2tr pg')]")
for row in rows:
    try: 
        codes.append(row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]/div[4]/div").get_attribute('textContent'))
    except:
        codes.append('null')
    try: 
        ISINs.append(row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]/div[3]/div").get_attribute('textContent'))
    except:
        ISINs.append('null')
        
dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'codes':codes,'ISINs':ISINs}) 
print (dataframe)
```

Import

```
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! but if I also want issuer and dates in the dataframe, I also need to create empty list right? or just another for loop for issuers :```issuers=[issuer.get_attribute('textContent') for issuer in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tb7']//tr[starts-with(@class,'tb2tr pg')]//td[1]/div[2]/div")]```

Comment: Yup if you want to append null you need something to append to.